# fix incompatibilities libreOffice files opened in MS Office 2007

Tags: libreoffice

I've just installed Ubuntu for a few days in dual-mode with win7. In Ubuntu, I opened some MS Office 2007 files and wrote reports. After I enter win7 again and open these reports, they all crashed and cannot be displayed
or many slides were missing, became blank

I had saved all files in Office formats already. The fact is they still crash.

Is there any way that I can have my reports back?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: See answers here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/193403/problems-in-libreoffice-writer-when-saving-as-docx/193519#193519 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/28342/how-to-maintain-document-compatibility-between-libreoffice-and-other-office-suit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of switching between two OSs, I still could not open the old files again. I learnt and already tried 2 things:

- installed LibreOffice in Win and opened the files again. It worked but as @kamil said, I lost several formats in those files and had to rework my reports
- back up any work doc before opening it with an unsure software

Thank you guys for anwsering my problem

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately NO. there is no full compatibility between libreoffice and ms office

You can save files as .doc and stay with office 2003 compatibility. That is better that .docx compatibility with office 2007/2010

Answer (score 0):

For best compatibiliry save Office 2007 files as Office 2003 (.doc .xls .ppt), if you use a lot of office 2007 new objects you going to lose it.  But th compatibility is better.

Comment: I did it but still could not open the files in Win using MS Office