# LibreOffice Writer problem with format

Tags: libreoffice

All of a sudden my LibreOffice Writer started acting up. My main question now is how to restore the appearance of a document I wrote a year ago that now has a first page whose appearance is unacceptable. I want it to be in the regular 8 1/2 x 11 page format, which is how it was originally. Now the print is big, bold, and italicized (I don't want this and didn't choose this.) and I can't even read the words on the right-hand side of the page. It kind of looks like it's in landscape mode, but I'm not sure.

I've tried using the Help tools but don't know what I'm doing. I've clicked on various things and nothing helps. I don't know how to move the side "borders". I tried to copy the whole thing so that I could maybe deal with it fresh on another page, but I can't even copy it - despite trying various things.

I haven't had Ubuntu for a year yet, but haven't had any seemingly insurmountable problems until now. I realize my description may not be helpful, but I hope somebody can work with me on this.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot (use http://imgur.com ), or copy of the document? Answers will otherwise likely just be guesses about what the problem is, not how to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

The open document format has changed quite much over the years and the document that you are trying to open might be written in an older format. Another page [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28342/how-to-maintain-document-compatibility-between-libreoffice-and-other-office-suit) explains the same problem. I am sorry but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Very unlikely - the document is just one year old, of cource a current LO cersion can work with such a file.